# converting continuous column to binary in python based on some condition

Tags: python

i want to convert one column of my dataframe to binary categorical of 0 and 1 based on some condition.THreshold is 4.If values of that particular column are above 4,1 should be assigned else 0

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a mask and then replace the values

```
mask = df['column_name'] > 4
df.loc[mask, 'column_name'] = 1
mask = df['column_name'] < 4
df.loc[mask, 'column_name'] = 0
```

or just use

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] < 4, 'column_name'] = 0
df.loc[df['column_name'] > 4, 'column_name'] = 1
```

in this case `mask` will just be a linear pandas series.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
def process_data():
    data = <your data>
    out_data = <define empty here as per data type>
    for item in data:#iterate through all items
        if <some condition>:
            #here process your items in data
            # add modified item in out_data
        else:
            #process else condition
            #add modified item in out_data
    return out_data

#usage
processed_data = process_data()
```

Comment: No, DON'T do this, never use for loops on a pandas dataframe, pandas are optimized in multiple ways and doing this completely kills that.